# How to get text from TinyMCE and save it to database

Tags: php, forms, tinymce

I'm using TinyMCE text editor on my website and I have problem with gettingtext from the TinyMCE and then insert to the db. I'm propably blind, but a don't see what wrong. Working with PDO.

Header, activate the editor

```
        <script src="//cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js"></script>
        <script>tinymce.init({ selector:'textarea' });</script>
```

Forms

```
<?php include "InsertArticles.php"; ?>

<div id="editor">
    <form method="post">
        <textarea name="Obsah"></textarea>
    </form>
</div>

<div id="inputaddnadpis">
    <form method="post">
        Nadpis: <input type="text" name="Nadpis">
    </form>
</div>

<form method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="Article" id="InsertArticles" value="Add article">
    <input type="submit" name="Tip" id="InsertTips" value="Add tip">
</form>
```

Insert

```
<?php  

include_once "db.php";
global $db;

    if (!empty($_POST["Article"])) {
        $sqlVlozeni = "INSERT INTO WEB_ARTICLE (Nazev, Clanek) VALUES (:nazev, :clanek)";
        $sqlProvedeni = $db->prepare($sqlVlozeni);
        $stav = $sqlProvedeni->execute(array(":nazev" => $_POST["Nadpis"], ":clanek" => $_POST["Obsah"]));
    }
```

?>

Comment: Character length for textarea? contain html tag? what field type on your database ?

Comment: @showdev ^--- Nice catch.

Comment: Yes, it's working, thanks.

Comment: Thank You for using prepared SQL statements :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Submitting the third form will not submit values from the first two forms.
In general, only the inputs inside a particular form will be submitted with that form.

Consider using only one `<form>` element around all of your inputs.

```html
<form method="post">

  <div id="editor">
    <textarea name="Obsah"></textarea>
  </div>

  <div id="inputaddnadpis">
    Nadpis: <input type="text" name="Nadpis">
  </div>

  <input type="submit" name="Article" id="InsertArticles" value="Add article">
  <input type="submit" name="Tip" id="InsertTips" value="Add tip">

</form>
```